# Not able to remove dynamically added imageview

Tags: android

In my application i have created a `ImageView` dynamically like below code:

```
dummyimage= new ImageView(mcontext);
dummyimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
dummyimage.setId(100);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100,30);
params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, 4);
params1.topMargin=-40; 
dummyimage.setLayoutParams(params1);

layout.addView(dummyimage);
```

When i try to remove this `ImageView` on clicking  of another view using below code the image is not removed:

```
layout.removeView(dummyimage);
```

also tried to remove using `layout.removeViewAt(100);` but the image is not removed.
How to fix this? Any help....

Comment: Call `invalidate()` on the view group after removing the view.

Comment: Is it possible to see ur entire class where  you are doing this?

Comment: @Tenfour04 not working...

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code

```
     dummyimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     layout.invalidate();
```

Comment: do this for params1 also.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a handler to post the modification, i sometimes had problems like this and doing that helped.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
           layout.removeView(dummyimage);
           // eventualy you could also call an layout.invalidate();
        }
    });
```